# Saving boolean return value into variable?

Tags: php

Is there a way to save a boolean true/false value in a function to a variable?

```
function check() {
    if(1 = 1) {
        return false;
    }
}
$status = check();
if($status === false) {
    echo "sign in please";
}
```

As of now `$status` comes out to be null. I don't like having to use `if(check() === false) {}` since a lot of my function have a lot of arguments. And setting `$status` within the function would defeat the purpose of a universal function that can be used for multiple variables.

How do you guys handle this?

EDIT: I apologize, something else in my code was causing it to be null. Tried to make a test (above code) and when it failed, I thought it was a worthy question :P

Answer (score 2):

A single equals sign is an assignment, not a comparison. You can fix it with a triple equals sign (which compares if two values are exactly the same).

```
function check() {
    if(1 === 1) { // Here
        return false;
    }
}
$status = check();
if($status === false) {
    echo "sign in please";
}
```

Comment: You should edit this to provide a better implementation of `check()`. As it is, it only returns a value when `1 === 1`, and `null` when it's not. I'd suggest just adding `return true;` after the closing `}` for the `if`, or better yet, just `return (1 === 1);` as the function body.

Comment: It's my fault, I was trying to make an example really fast